# Newton method norm of error is proportional to norm of residual?

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson

Let $F(x):\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. Newton's method is:
$x_{k+1} := x_k + d_k$, where $d_k$ is computed to satisfy
$F'(x_k)d_k = -F(x_k)$.

If the error at the current step is $e_k = x^* - x_k$, then why is $\|e_k\|$ proportional to $\|F(x_k)\|$?

It makes sense since $F(x_k)\rightarrow 0$ iff $\|e_k\|\rightarrow 0$, but I just can't see why they're proportional, something isn't clicking.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_k$ is close to the solution $x^*$, the Jacobian of $F$ should not change very much and the linear approximation to $F$ about $x^*$ should be accurate, so $e_k$ should be approximately equal to $-DF(x^*)^{-1}F(x_k)$. Then $\frac{\| e_k \|}{\| F(x_k) \|}$ will be approximately bounded by the smallest and largest singular values of $DF(x^*)^{-1}$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a bit slow today, where did $DF(x^*)^{-1}F(x_k)$ come from?

Comment: @user302157 Linear approximation says $F(x_k) \approx DF(x^*) e_k$, now solve for $e_k$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Isn't there supposed to be a minus then? Since the linearisation of $F(x)$ at $x_k$ is $F(x)\approx F(x_k) + DF(x_k)(x-x_k)$. So $F(x_k)\approx -DF(x^*)(x^*-x_k)$ for $x^*$ close to $x_k$.

Comment: @user302157 Yes, with your sign convention for $e_k$ there should be a minus sign. Of course this minus sign has no bearing on the norms.